# generar recta en mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

quiero graficar la distancia de un punto a una recta con mathplotlib, logro graficar la recta, el punto, sacar la distancia, pero no puedo hacer que se grafique la distancia de ese punto a la recta, probe creando una linea con axhline, pero es fijo, asi que si cambio el valor, la recta no sirve, dejo el codigo si sirve de algo.

```
def ecuacion_recta(m, b,r,d5,d6):
x = range(-10, 10)
y = range(r)


plt.plot(x, [m*i+b for i in x])
plt.plot(2, 7, marker="o")



plt.axhline(0, color="black")
plt.axvline(0, color="black")
plt.xlim(-11, 11)
plt.ylim(-11, 11)

#intento de graficar la distancia 
plt.plot(y, [b for j in y], )



plt.show()
```

se imprime esto si lo realizo con estos datos m= 0.5 b = -1 r = 6.28... d5 = 2 d6 = 7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco su guía y tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo (ver [base](http://www.objetos.unam.mx/matematicas/leccionesMatematicas/02/2_044/index.html), [ejes a escalas iguales](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/matplotlib/how-to-make-a-square-plot-with-equal-axes-in-matplotlib/)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ecuacion_recta(m, b,r,d5,d6):
    x = range(-10, 10)
    punto = (2,7)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

    plt.plot(x, [m*i+b for i in x])
    plt.plot(punto[0], punto[1], marker="o")


    plt.axhline(0, color="black")
    plt.axvline(0, color="black")
    plt.xlim(-11, 11)
    plt.ylim(-11, 11)

    c = punto[1] + (1/m)*punto[0]

    perpendicular = [ -(1/m)*i + c for i in x ]

    plt.plot(x, perpendicular)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # m= 0.5 b = -1 r = 6.28... d5 = 2 d6 = 7

    ecuacion_recta(0.5,-1,6,2,7)
```

Resultado:

[image: subplot matplotlib recta que pasa por un punto y se corta perpendicularmente con otra]

Comment: Muchas gracias, nunca imagine que seria así, era mas simple de lo que pensaba, gracias <333

Comment: Nada :) me alegra haber ayudado